# Pandas ignores to_string formatters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `z` that I want to print with formatting

```
z
Out[43]: 
      Value
0   1.69998
1      0.98
2  0.849991
```

Now, I want to affect the format of the column. I do

```
z.to_string(formatters=['{:3.2f}'.format])
Out[46]: '      Value\n0   1.69998\n1      0.98\n2  0.849991'
z.to_string(formatters=['ZZZZ'.format])
Out[47]: '      Value\n0   1.69998\n1      0.98\n2  0.849991'
```

It seems to be completely ignore the command. @jlandercy's example works for me -- somehow, my DataFrame is broken. I'm working on a (non)working example to post here: If I store it as json and re-read it again, it magically starts working:

```
z2    # my df
Out[75]: 
      value
0   1.69998
1      0.98
2  0.849991
print(z2.to_string(formatters=['{:.3f}'.format])) # does not work
      value
0   1.69998
1      0.98
2  0.849991
# but storing as json and reading again works
print(pd.read_json(z2.to_json()).to_string(formatters=['{:.3f}'.format]))
  value
0 1.700
1 0.980
2 0.850
```

Comment: What is your expected output of your fomatting? 3 digits before the decimal and 2 decimal places?

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: @jlandercy the same as yours, `0.23.4`

Comment: 2 things:


1. I think you're just missing the fact that you get a string representation of the dataframe, using `print()` would be more efficient to view it.
2. If I understand correctly, you want to round to 3 decimal digits? Then use the `{.3f}` format

Comment: That's why Im asking what his expected output is, now we're all just playing the guess game

Answer (score 3):

It seems that when the data type of the column is `object`, `pandas` completely ignores the formatting without raising warnings.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to apply formatting to get floats with 3 numbers before decimal and 2 after, you're formatting is incorrect. The first number in `{3.2f}` represents the **length** of the number including the decimal. So you would need the following:

```
print(z.to_string(formatters=['{:06.2f}'.format]))

   Value
0 001.70
1 000.98
2 000.85
```

Comment: My issue is not the exact formatting, rather that the formatter is completely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Using Pandas `0.23.4`, the following example works as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
# pd.__version__ # '0.23.4'
z = pd.DataFrame([1.69998, 0.98, 0.849991], columns=["value"])
s = z.to_string(formatters=['{:.3f}'.format])
print(s)
```

Returns:

```
  value
0 1.700
1 0.980
2 0.850
```

As you noticed, if `dtypes` is `object`, the method `to_string` ignores formatters:

```
z.astype(object).to_string(formatters=['{:.2f}'.format])
# '      value\n0   1.69998\n1      0.98\n2  0.849991'
```

Comment: This example works. I'm trying to understand what exactly is wrong with my dataframe.

Comment: Could you check the type of your value column with `df.dtypes`? @FooBar

Comment: Without having the very same of your it is complicated to understand why.

Comment: @Erfan Indeed, that was the smoking gun.

Comment: Always the small things you forget the check :) @FooBar